# How a web app identify if a click came from another web app via code?

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, http-headers, legacy

we have a web application that users can take online reports from ou ERP system data... And we have another web application that is used by our teachers and employees.

We can't change the ERP web app because its a closed DLL, in this case we made some extended functionality  in our custom internal web app and we are willing to put this functionality on the "menu" of the ERP web app.

I need to integrate the two applications in the following way:

When I click in the menu of the ERP web app, I want that our internal web app assert that the click have come from our ERP web app and not typed in the URL, this is possible?

Comment: In simple words I want to identify a click origin.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the ServerVariable  called HTTP_REFERER  below is a link to some documentation

http://www.w3schools.com/asp/coll_servervariables.asp

Comment: I'm going to delete my answer and just add a link to yours: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer

Comment: This is easily spoofed, so if security is an issue, I wouldn't use this.

Answer (score 0):

Look for the server variable HTTP_REFERER in your internal app's request.  You should be able to compare that against a known value.